# Cannot get image on node from angular

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, angular6, formidable

I have a reactive form in angular 6 that I try to use it to submit an image and some text fields.

Here it is

```
<form [formGroup]="imageUpload" (ngSubmit)="imageUploadSubmitted()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div id="imageDrop" (click)='imageInput.click()' (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" #imageDrop></div> 
  <input type="file" formControlName="imageInput" required #imageInput id="imageInput" name = 'image' (change)='imageChange($event)' accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif" > <!-- hide with css -->
    <input type="text" formControlName="imageName" placeholder="name" required >
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

So either you click on the drop area the file picker opens -or you drop an image.

Either way, get the image and save it in a variable.

```
  selectedFile:File=null;

  drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset();  
    this.selectedFile = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    this.checkfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }

  imageChange(e){        
    this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
    this.checkfiles(e.target.files);    
  }
```

check the selected files

```
   acceptedImageTypes = {'image/png': true,'image/jpeg': true,'image/gif': true};
  checkfiles(files){      
    if (this.acceptedImageTypes[files[0].type] !== true){
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="Not an image";          
      return;   
    }
    else if (files.length>1){
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="Only one image/time";           
      return;   
    }    
    else { this.readfiles(files); }
  }
```

cool, now prepare an image preview and append it in the drop area

```
  readfiles(files){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let image = new Image();      
    reader.onload =  (event) =>{      
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="";                
      let fileReader = event.target as FileReader;
      image.src = fileReader.result;
      image.width = 150; 
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.appendChild(image);  
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);        
  }
```

ok, now when the form is submitted set the `selectedFile` as the file input value and submit the form.

First I try to set the value of `imageInput` by changing its `value`. Then, I also try to append a new form control with the `selectedFile` value.

**Both console logs show a proper image object, but when they get to nodejs v8.11.1, they appear empty.**

I also tried to create a default HTML5 form data object (named `fd`) and send it on the same service. **This also appears empty**

```
  imageUploadSubmitted(){
    let input = this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput as any;        
    input.value = this.selectedFile;  
    this.imageUpload.addControl('newImage', new FormControl(this.selectedFile));
    console.log('imageInput value = ',this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.value);
    console.log('newImage value = ',this.imageUpload.controls.newImage.value);    
    //const fd = new FormData();
    //fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.mapcmsService.uploadImage(this.imageUpload.value).subscribe((data) =>{
      if(data.success){                  
        alert('ok');
      }
      else{
        alert('nope');
      }
    })
  }
```

This is my service

```
  uploadImage(data){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization',this.cma_token);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/map/upload/image', data, {headers:headers}).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

And this is my node code, where I would like to use formidable, but I dont have values to work on, so I get the error that `path` is not defined, since there is no value.

```
router.post('/upload/image',validate.required(),(req, res)=>{ 
  console.log('FILES - ',req.body);//<< all files appear empty

  let oldpath;
  let newpath;
  let textDate = String(Date.now());
  let newname ;
  let type;
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {    

    oldpath = files.imageInput.path;//ofcourse gives an error and crash node
    newpath = path.join(__dirname, '/angular-src/src/app/assets/images/',newname) ;
    newname = textDate+files.imageInput.name;
    type = files.imageInput.type;
  });

});
```

This route has a `validate` middleware that checks for the user token. The user token is set in the headers, in the service.

So, in front-end the file values look ok, but I get no values in the server. My front-end looks fine to me and the server code is based on the formidable example.

So what is wrong? The service? Some node parameters? Security issues? Please help me debug this. I cannot find the error, so this is why I put a lot of details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned :

> `//const fd = new FormData();`
>
> `//fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);`

Your request data should be a `FormData` as your server expect and it should work. if not - provide a server-side code part and will see.

And could you provide a `plnkr` or `stackblitz` sample? not sure what exactly you are passing via `POST` request